# How to do safe backups on Azure?

Tags: azure, storage, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I recently created a SQL Server Virtual Machine on Microsoft Azure. Now I defined my backup jobs and store them on a different Drive. I want to ensure that my backups are safe, meaning on a zone redundant storage.
I heard and read about the storage but I don't understand how to create it and make sure that my SQL Backup is stored their directly.
Is there any other safe option? On AWS you can save your stuff on a Bucket which you can access like a mapped drive... What does Azure offer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a storage account you can select the type of redundancy you want.
Even after creating the storage account you change it properties.

You can attach a new disk to a VM you can select any storage account in your subscription. So if your storage account was zone redundant and your created a VHD in that storage account the data in the VHD will be zone redundant.

You can learn about different storage accounts here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-introduction/

Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Based on which version of SQL Server you are using you may be able to directly backup from SQL Server to Azure blob storage without saving it to local disk.

Comment: ahh that was the feature of 2014, backup online ? I use 2014

Comment: Keep in mind that disk is also using azure blob storage. However disk is constrained to 1 TB storage limit where as azure blob storage has much higher limits. Since you are on a very recent version of SQL Server 2014 you know what to do.

Comment: so when I have a storage account and I attach any disk to any of my vm's its bound to that account and saved redundant already. Did i got that right? thanks